# How to add custom class to ng-bootstrap tooltip

Tags: angular, tooltip, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a custom class to an ng-bootstrap tooltip but it won't apply it.

HTML

```
<i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true" [ngbTooltip]="infoTooltipTemplate" [tooltipClass]="info-tooltip" placement="top"></i>
```

CSS

```
.info-tooltip .tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 340px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #00000040;
}
```

The styling for the tooltip still remains the same as the default styling. I'm working on Angular 7 with @ng-bootstrap version 4.2.2

Answer (score 7):

Here is the example of custom class from ng-bootstrap website. Link to stackblitz: [link](https://stackblitz.com/run?file=app/tooltip-customclass.ts)

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" ngbTooltip="Nice class!"
tooltipClass="my-custom-class">
Tooltip with custom class
</button>
```

CSS

```
.my-custom-class .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  font-size: 125%;
}
.my-custom-class .arrow::before {
  border-top-color: darkgreen;
}
```

I hope this helps.

**Update**

As Devin mentioned in the comment, you must add the custom styles in your global stylesheet. Thanks Devin.

Comment: For anyone who couldn't get this working, make sure you add the custom styles in your global stylesheet. Won't work at component level.

Comment: Keeping custom styles in global css file is really important. Thanks Devin & sosNiLa for this point

Answer (score 3):

You can use that in your css :

```
::ng-deep .tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 340px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #00000040;
}
```

It also means that you can remove this : `[tooltipClass]="info-tooltip"`

So it'll just be :

```
<i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true" [ngbTooltip]="infoTooltipTemplate" placement="top"></i>
```

Comment: Why i can't override the opacity of tooltip through custom class? ::ng-deep .custom_class {opacity: 1;} but still the opacity is 0.9 (default)

Comment: !important solved the problem, now - _::ng-deep .custom_class {opacity: 1 !important;}_

Answer (score 2):

No need to change your global stylesheet. This is enough:

```
::ng-deep .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  font-size: 125%;
}
```

Also, if you need to limit the change only for that component, you should use :host

```
:host ::ng-deep .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  font-size: 125%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If the component is not having `encapsulation:viewencapsulation.None` then use `::ng-deep` after that give custom class & tooltip-inner as below and give whatever the CSS properties you want. Then it will not override other CSS classes in other components & we can customize the ngbtooltip.

```html
<label [ngbTooltip]="infoTooltipTemplate" [tooltipClass]="customClass">
  <span> custom ngb tooltip </span>
</label>
```

```css
::ng-deep .customClass .tooltip-inner {
  color: blue;
  width: 80px;
}
```

If the component is having `encapsulation:viewencapsulation.None` then directly give the custom CSS class & tooltip-inner as below and give whatever the CSS properties you want. Then it will not override other CSS classes in other components and we can customise the ngbtooltip.

```html
<label [ngbTooltip]="infoTooltipTemplate" [tooltipClass]="customClass">
  <span> custom ngb tooltip </span>
</label>
```

```css
.customClass .tooltip-inner {
  color: blue;
  width: 80px;
}
```